# exporting android app : Proguard returned with error code 2

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to export an android app on eclipse I have created my keystore and alias but when I click "Finish" I've got this error :

```
Proguard returned with error code 2. See console
Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion'
has value '1.7', but '1.8' is required.
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

My eclipse.ini is :

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
E:/Programmes/Java/jdk1.8.0_20/bin/javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
```

My Path is:

```
E:\Programmes\Ruby200-x64\bin;C:\Users\Benoit\AppData\Roaming\npm;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;E:\Programmes\apache-maven-3.2.3\bin
```

My Java_HOME is:

```
E:\Programmes\Java\jdk1.8.0_20
```

I've seen several SO post about this but none worked for me, anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion'
has value '1.7', but '1.8' is required. Did you update JRE?

Comment: Wow that is so obvious that I didn't thought about it. Updating and telling you in few.

Comment: That kind of worked because I've got another error the thing is that in fact I need to export for java 1.7 since I use google app engine which only work with 1.7.
`Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find superclass or interface javax.jdo.spi.PersistenceCapable
...`
But when I change my Path and eclipse.ini for 1.7 I've got the same error (`has value '1.7', but '1.8' is required.`)

Comment: Weirdly I can still build and lauch my app when I'm in 1.8.

Comment: `Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find superclass or interface javax.jdo.spi.PersistenceCapable` might be due to code compression. You would need to customize some thing in Proguard properties

Comment: Ok thanks, but I have no idea where it is and what I need to change, can you help me ?

Comment: Yes. Try adding `-dontwarn javax.jdo.**
-dontwarn com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.**` in your proguard.txt file. which will be in root folder of your app if you haven't changed its location.

Comment: yes thanks it worked, post your answer so I can validate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,

your error is:

```
Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion' has value '1.7', but '1.8' is required.
```

So please update your Java Runtime Environment.

And then, you are getting this warning:

```
Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find superclass or interface javax.jdo.spi.PersistenceCapable
```

You would need to customize your proguard.txt's configuration for this:

Try this:

```
-dontwarn javax.jdo.**
-dontwarn com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.**
```

This will not cause that warning to be shown.

Hope it helps.